# How to paste names of an object within a loop?

Tags: r, lapply, names

```
root <- c(54, 7, 125, 80, 0, 60, 30, 51, 23, 7)
smith <- c(112, 2, 104, 19, 7, 12, 61, 80, 4, 49)
kohli <- c(43, 31, 25, 186, 75, 37, 40, 1, 4, 130)
williamson <- c(22, 73, 98, 38, 61, 9, 22, 101, 0, 12)

batsmen <- list(root, smith, kohli, williamson)
bat_names <- c("Joe Root", "Steve Smith", "Virat Kohli", "Kane Williamson")
names(batsmen) <- bat_names

bat_averages <- function(x) {
  paste(names(x), "average is", mean(x))
}

lapply(batsmen, bat_averages)
$`Joe Root`
[1] " average is 43.7"

$`Steve Smith`
[1] " average is 45"

$`Virat Kohli`
[1] " average is 57.2"

$`Kane Williamson`
[1] " average is 43.6"
```

How can I print the names of each object in batsmen inside the function? I think I understand why using a loop/lapply doesn't work with names(), but I can't figure out how to get the desired result. Many thanks.

Comment: `sapply(batsmen, mean)` gives a more desirable result

Comment: Modify the function to `bat_averages <- function(x) {
   paste0(x, " average is ", mean(batsmen[[x]]))
}` and then do `lapply(names(batsmen), bat_averages)`.